# alias doesn't work in fish shell on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, fish

I've been struggling with an issue that I cannot find mentioned anywhere and I cannot trace down. I can't leverage any of the alias command functionality in fish, which also breaks fish integrations that rely on that command (like `zoxide init fish`). I can manually define aliases fine (they're just functions after all), but commands like `alias ls "ls -lah"` don't work.

My suspicion is that somehow it's prefering to interpret `alias` as the macOS executable rather than the fish built-in:

```
> alias foo="echo foo"
> foo
fish: Unknown command: foo
> type -a alias
alias is /usr/bin/alias
> alias --help
/usr/bin/alias: line 4: alias: --: invalid option
alias: usage: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
```

I have many fish aliases defined manually in my configs and they work, just the `alias` built-in itself seems to be broken.

### Follow-up

Some requested additional details that don't fit in a comment:

```
> fish --version
fish, version 3.7.0
> set -S fish_function_path
$fish_function_path: set in global scope, unexported, with 6 elements
$fish_function_path[1]: |/Users/<REDACTED>/.config/fish/functions|
$fish_function_path[2]: |/opt/homebrew/etc/fish/functions|
$fish_function_path[3]: |/Users/<REDACTED>/.local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d|
$fish_function_path[4]: |/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.7.0/share/fish/vendor_functions.d|
$fish_function_path[5]: |/opt/homebrew/share/fish/vendor_functions.d|
$fish_function_path[6]: |/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.7.0/share/fish/functions|
```

Comment: `alias` is defined as a function in fish. What is your fish version? What is the contents of $fish_function_path -- `set -S fish_function_path`

Comment: @glennjackman thank you for this, this got me some headway - I edited the question to include the output, and also started grepping those paths to find where `alias` is defined, and found that if I explicitly `source /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.7.0/share/fish/functions/alias.fish` then the `alias` command works normally in that session. Any idea why that would be necessary when that file is already in the search path?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use [`abbr`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html) instead:

```
abbr -a ls ls -lah
```

Abbreviations are better for multiple reasons:

- if you overwrite a basic command like `ls`, they let you skip the auto-expansion at times, if needed. It's not unikely to encounter such situations and you won't have to temporarily remove the alias if they occur.
- they work much better with autocompletions
- they save the original expanded command in the history. Which could be a slight disadvantage if it's your own machine and you prefer to save aliases instead to e.g. remember them. But otherwise, if working with multiple people especially, saving the original commands makes debugging easier.

Comment: This does not solve the problem for third party scripts which (rightly) assume that `alias` works, such as `zoxide init fish` which was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with [function auto-loading](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#syntax-function-autoloading) - I had a file `~/.config/fish/functions/alias.fish` with some aliases in it, but this caused fish not to read the main definition at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.7.0/share/fish/functions/alias.fish` because fish explicitly looks for the first file whose name matches the function name. Renaming the file solved the issue.